# Using SimpleDB NextToken when records in query are updated

Tags: amazon-simpledb, boto

I have a case where we are doing a select on a domain like:

```
select * from mydomain where some_val = 'foo' and some_date < '2012-03-01T00:00+01:00'
```

When iterating the results of this query - we are doing some work and then updating the row and setting the field `some_date` to the current date/time. Marking that it's processed.

The question I have is will the nexttoken request break when it returns to simpledb to get the next set of records? When it returns to get the next batch - all of the ones in the first batch will now have some_date with a value that no longer is within the original query range.

I don't know how the next-token is implemented to know whether its just a pointer to the next item or whether it somehow is an offset that might "skip" a whole batch of records.

So if we retrieved 3 records at a time and I had this in my domain:

```
record 1, '2012-01-12T19:20+01:00'
record 2, '2012-02-14T19:20+01:00'
record 3, '2012-01-22T19:20+01:00'
record 4, '2012-01-21T19:20+01:00'
record 5, '2012-02-22T19:20+01:00'
record 6, '2012-01-20T19:20+01:00'
record 7, '2012-01-18T19:20+01:00'
record 8, '2012-01-17T19:20+01:00'
record 9, '2012-02-12T19:20+01:00'
```

My first execution I would get: record `1, 2, 3`
If i set their `some_date` field to: `'2012-03-12T19:20+01:00'` before returning for the next-token batch - would the next-token request then return `4,5,6`? Or would it return `7,8,9` (because the token was set to start at the 4th record and now `1,2,3` are no longer in the result set).

If it is important - we are using the boto library (python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would the next-token request then return 4,5,6? Or would it return
>   7,8,9 [...]?

Good question, this can indeed be a bit confusing - still anything but the former (i.e. `4,5,6`) wouldn't make sense for practical usage and [Amazon SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) works like so accordingly, see [Select](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SDB_API_Select.html):

> Operations that run longer than 5 seconds return a time-out error
>   response or a partial or empty result set. Partial and empty result
>   sets contain a NextToken value, **which allows you to continue the
>   operation from where it left off** *[emphasis mine]*

Please take note of the additional note in section *Request Parameters* though, which might be a bit surprising eventually:

> **Note**
>
> The response to a Select operation with ConsistentRead set to
>   true returns a consistent read. However, **for any following Select
>   operation requests that include a NextToken value, Amazon SimpleDB
>   ignores the ConsistentRead field**, and the subsequent results are
>   eventually consistent. *[emphasis mine]*

Comment: Thanks - what you said makes sense.  We'll work with it on that assumption.  If we ever see evidence to the contrary in our system I will make sure to report back here.